# jquery input radio on click not working

Tags: jquery

How to clear the value of input id "price" and disable it when clicking on radio button id "meta_price_type_0" ,"meta_price_type_1",meta_price_type_2

```
 <input id="price" type="text" name="price" value="200" >
 <input type="radio" name="meta[4]" id="meta_price_type_0" value="Has Price Above0">
 <input type="radio" name="meta[4]" id="meta_price_type_1" value="Has Price Above1">
 <input type="radio" name="meta[4]" id="meta_price_type_2" value="Has Price Above2">
```

Comment: Hi regent I tried this for first id 
    $("input:radio[id=meta_price_type_0]").click(function(){

        
            $('#price').val('');
        });

Comment: @govindak, try `$("#meta_price_type_0").click(function(){ $('#price').val(''); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#meta_price_type_0, #meta_price_type_1, #meta_price_type_3").click(function(){
    $("#price").val("");
    $("#price").attr("disabled", true);
              OR (use either)
    $("#price").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: You forgot to disable `input`

Comment: `.attr("disabled", true)` will work on js less than 1.6

Comment: Cant you guys see 
    $("#price").prop("disabled", true);
in my answer ????????? Strange...

Comment: @Yunus I wanted to point out that it should be `$("#price").attr("disabled", "disabled");`, but it turns out that `$("#price").attr("disabled", true);` works aswell

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
    $("#price").val("").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

If you have other inputs with `type="radio"` you might wanna use the following code.

```
$('input[id*="meta_price_type_"]').on('click',function(){
    $("#price").val("").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: @ Maveric - What if the user clicks on the first radio itself with ID price ..???? don't you think even that will disable the first radio option... ??

Comment: The input with `id="price"` is of `type="text"`

Answer (score 0):

you can do that on this way:

```
$('#meta_price_type_0, #meta_price_type_1, #meta_price_type_2').click(function(){
     $('#price').val('').attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

Or you can put a class in each input radio, this will allow you to work with a more understanding jquery and you can use other elements to do the same...

```
<input type="radio" name="meta[4]" value="Has Price Above0" class="clear-the-price">
<input type="radio" name="meta[4]" value="Has Price Above1" class="clear-the-price">
<input type="radio" name="meta[4]" value="Has Price Above2" class="clear-the-price">
```

And your jquery selector will be like:

```
$('input.clear-the-price').click(function(){
    $('#price').val('').attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle where you can se this script in action: http://jsfiddle.net/w9a8u4f2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input[type='radio'][name*='meta']" ).on( "click", function ( ) {

    $( "#price" ).val( "" );
    $( "#price" ).prop( "disabled", true );


});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kxtvmm1m/